# Unable to specify .RowSource for Combo Box

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a dependent combo box in Excel using VBA. Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub conduitTypeBox_Change()

Select Case conduitTypeBox.Value
    Case Is = "IMC"
        conduitSizeBox.RowSource = "imcSize"
    Case Is = "LFMC"
        conduitSizeBox.RowSource = "lfmcSize"
    Case Is = "RMC"
        conduitSizeBox.RowSource = "rmcSize"
    Case Is = "PVC (Schedule 80)"
        conduitSizeBox.RowSource = "pvc80Size"
    Case Is = "PVC (Schedule 40)"
        conduitSizeBox.RowSource = "pvc40Size"
    Case Is = "PVC (Type A)"
        conduitSizeBox.RowSource = "pvcaSize"
    Case Is = "PVC (Type EB)"
        conduitSizeBox.RowSource = "pvcebSize"
End Select

End Sub
```

The concept is that the user selects a type of conduit (ex. "IMC") in the first combo box and then a second combo box populates with sizes unique to the conduit type. I created a name for the range of the data using the Name Manager (and ensured it has the scope of the entire workbook), however I am getting run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. I understand what the issue is, but I'm not entirely sure why it's an issue. When I type "`conduitSizeBox.`", `RowSource` does not appear in the list of available properties. Would anyone have any idea why?

I tried looking for other properties and didn't find anything that fit my needs.

Comment: You should refer to the address of the named range. Use something like Range("myrange").Address(TRUE, TRUE, x1A1, TRUE)

Comment: That would suggest that the control is not a listbox or combobox (or you are using a Mac). Or it's on a worksheet, in which case you need the `Listfillrange` property.

Comment: Thanks Rory. This did the trick. The guide I followed used a user form, my work was done in a worksheet.

Comment: The Is = is not required in your select case block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Listfillrange` property instead of `Rowsource`.